# нужна ли запятая перед словом "кредиторская"

Tags: пунктуация

"при таких обстоятельствах кредиторская задолженность в размере 172,00 руб. подлежит списанию."

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна.

Обороты с предлогом "при" не требуют постановки знаков препинания. Но такой оборот может иногда обособляться — если он довольно большой и там звучит пауза.